# Algorithm fails to find triangular number with more than 500 divisors

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been working through a problem from the Project Euler website ([problem 12](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12)) but I can't figure out why my code isn't working.  The obective of the code is that it should find the smallest triangular number that has over 500 divisors.

```
private static long triangleNumber() {

    long currentTriangleNumber = 0;
    long triangleNumber = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while (triangleNumber == 0) {
        counter++;
        currentTriangleNumber += counter;
        int divisorCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
            if ((currentTriangleNumber % i) == 0) {
                divisorCounter++;
                if (divisorCounter >= 500) {
                    triangleNumber = currentTriangleNumber;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return triangleNumber;
}
```

The code returns 842161320, which is not the right answer. As far as I can see, the problem does not lie within the syntax and the code does not output any sort of error message. The answer, from what I've briefly looked up should be 76576500.

Can explain why the code is not finding the solution?

Comment: What means "not working"?

Comment: It's not the right answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. You are referring to an off-site resource (programming challenge website) to defined the problem. You need to state **in the post on this site** what the program should do, what you'd like to see as output and what you are seeing that you think is wrong. Please read [the FAQ tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start..

Comment: @SDR What happened when you stepped through your code with a debugger? What test case is failing? What happened when you logged values? Where does your expectation specifically break from the computational reality?

Comment: And what is the right answer? If you want a good answer, you should explain what your code is supposed to do, what output you expect, what output you get, and give any error messages, if they exist.

Comment: I have made a fairly substantial edit to help you get on the right track in asking questions here.  Obviously - you have the option to revert your question back to the original, but I hope when you look at the edits they will be useful to you in suggesting how to ask a question on here and hopefully might attract more answers and suggestions for you. **It would still benefit from** a description of debugging you have done and why that hasn't revealed your problem to you, plus some more words describing the algorithm / design you intended to implement. Good Luck!

Comment: Three hints: 1) Your fundamental idea is OK - not the super-fastest, but reasonable. 2) Think about how many divisors are indicated by each `(currentTriangleNumber % i) == 0` 3) In light of 2), think about what you need the limit on your `for` loop to be...

Comment: Thank you for the help, Richard, I'll try to keep in mind what you said when I post another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the for loop that you use to find the number of divisors:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
```

You test each of these `i`s to see if it's a divisor, and if there are 500 of them, you stop.

Which is nice, but why stop at `counter`? Look at the list given in the problem description:

```
#1 1: 1
#2 3: 1,3
#3 6: 1,2,3,6
#4 10: 1,2,5,10
#5 15: 1,3,5,15
#6 21: 1,3,7,21
#7 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
```

Take the number 21. It is the triangle number 6. Thus, in your program, its counter is going to be `6`.

It has 4 divisors. But only two of them are less than or equal to 6. So your program will say that it only has two divisors, which is clearly wrong.

You have to count all the divisors, including the number itself. For the true answer (76576500), `counter` is going to be `12375`. You will only be counting divisors that are less than `12375`, and it has less than 500 of those.

Your program actually tells us what the first triangle is, which has 500 divisors less than its index.